# ARKit anchor drift, localization, image anchors

Tags: ios, arkit

I'm working on an ARKit application, in which I place several anchor around a room, save the world map data to a server, and then restore that data and the anchors on a different device. Obviously, localization and drifting of the anchors is something the app has to cope with.

My question is, can placing an image anchor in the room and scanning that image help with re-localizing after re-loading the world map data? Would ARKit use the pose of a scanned image as feedback into it's re-localization process? For the app I'm working on, it is a possibility to have an image marker (such as a QR code) placed at a consistent location within a room, such that the app can be sure the image has not physically moved. Would scanning such an image and placing an image anchor at its location help with re-localizing when the world map is later loaded on a different device?